# preventDefault() submitting form

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to jQuery and JavaScript in general.

I have a form, and what I want to do it have the form run a function to make sure everything is there, and all the variables are correct then submit.

I have used `onclick` value to the submit button and have it run a function that uses `preventDefault()`. I am not sure if im using it correctly but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is what I have and when you click submit, it just submits even if the if statement is false.

```
function checkSubmitStatus() {
    $("#myform").submit(function(event){
        if( whatever==true) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }
    });
}

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  onClick="checkSubmitStatus()">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By putting `$("#myform").submit(...)` inside the `checkSubmitStatus()` function, you're attaching the submit handler after the button is clicked and the form is already submitted. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myform").submit(function(event){
    if(whatever) { 
       event.preventDefault();  
    }  
  });
});
</script>

<form id="myform">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thnaks, your detailed answer was what i needed, you not only helped me fix my issue but also realize an issue i didn't notice! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Change

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  onClick="checkSubmitStatus()">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
```

and change your javascript to

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event){
    if( whatever==true)
    {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't attach `onSubmit` to an input tag, only to a form tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can just drop the `checkSubmitStatus()` function.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event){
  if(whatever == true) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
  }
});
```

Also drop this:

```
onClick="checkSubmitStatus()"
```

Answer (score 3):

In the onclick event handler, if you return false the form will not submit. Try doing this:

```
function checkSubmitStatus() {
   if(validationSuccess==true)
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  onClick="return checkSubmitStatus()">
```

Comment: Upvoting because this solution is what *I* was looking for; something that does not use jQuery (even though the OP is specific to jQuery!)

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor this slightly...

```
function checkSubmitStatus() {
    if( whatever==true) {
          return false;
    }
    return true;
}

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  onClick="return checkSubmitStatus()">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let button = document.getElementById('submit');
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.innerHTML = "Button clicked!";

});
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question within the scope of what the author is asking as it does not use JQuery. However it has great value as an answer if you can add a description as to what your code does and what it is achieving differently.