# Send selectbox value to php variables without page reloading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm learning AJAX by reading some online tutorials, so please understand I am very new to AJAX and programming in general. I have managed to do the following with 3 selectboxes:

- populates selectbox 2 based on selection from selectbox 1
- populates selectbox 3 based on selection from selectbox 2

Everything is working **perfectly**

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(".sport").change(function()
 {
  var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;
  
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_sport.php",
   dataType : 'html',
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
      $(".tournament").html(html);
   } 
   });
  });
 
 
 $(".tournament").change(function()
 {
  var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;
 
  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_round.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".round").html(html);
   } 
   });
  });
 
});
</script>
```

**Here is an Example**

[image]

**What I want to do**

- I would like to send the value of the 3 selectboxes to 3 php variables **without the form reloading.**

**My Problem**

When the user clicks submit:

1. The form reloads (which I dont want)
2. The selectbox values does not get send to my php variables

my code to get the values after submit is clicked is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$a = $_POST['sport'];
$b = $_POST['tournament'];
:
}
```

However my code is flawed as I mentioned above.

If any one can help me to ***explain how to send my form data to the 3 php variables without the form reloading*** it will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to submit your form when you click the button, you need to set that input as `button` and not `submit`. You can, also, attach the `submit` event handler to the form and prevent it to submit:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //This is one option
  return false; //This is another option (and return true if you want to submit it).
});
```

So, being said this, you could probably do something like:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  var formData = $(this).serialize();
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'yoururl',
    data: formData,
    type: 'post', //Based on what you have in your backend side
    success: function(data) {
      //Whatever you want to do once the server returns a success response
    }

  });
});
```

In your backend:

```
if (isset($_POST["sport"])) {
  //Do something with sport
}
if (isset($_POST["tournament"])) {
  //Do something with torunament
}

echo "Successfull response!"; //You have to "write" something in your response and that is what the frontend is going to receive.
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the javascript function [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194673/preventdefault-submitting-form).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<button>Submit</button>` element instead of `<input type="submit"/>` since the submit automatically submits the form.

Edit: And you would have to use on.('click') instead of looking for submit event in your jQuery.