# Why does a `submit` event listener not work on a submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

When I use the `click` event, my code works and it prevents the form from submitting. However, when I use the `submit` event, it does not. Why?

```js
const submitMessage = document.getElementById("submitButton");

submitMessage.addEventListener("submit", sendMessage, false);

function sendMessage(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Made it");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="submitButton" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: already answered, here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194673/preventdefault-submitting-form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [preventDefault() submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194673/preventdefault-submitting-form)

Answer (score 16):

> When I use the 'click' event, my code works and it prevents the form from submitting. However, when I use this code it does not. Why?

The `submit` event is only triggered on the `<form>` element.

Since you say it works for `click`, I *assume* you are not binding the handler to the `<form>` element.

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit):

> The submit event is fired when a form is submitted.
>
> Note that submit is fired **only** on the [form element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form), not the [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) or [submit input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)

Answer (score 1):

If `submitMessage` is the form then make sure that the submit button has the `type` attribute set as `submit` in the html file. In my case, the type of the submit button was `button` and it gave me headaches because I thought the problem was in the js file. It looks like a small problem but it can get you pretty stuck.