# addEventListener with 'submit' is not working, actually keep refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, submit, addeventlistener, preventdefault

im trying to do submit with enter in the form tag, but its not working
here is my code

```js
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('it works')
})
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <form>
                <input></input>
                <button type="submit" id='button'></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The `<input>` element's end tag is forbidden.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener using submit is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637920/addeventlistener-using-submit-is-not-working)

Comment: try removing the `<form>` tag, and changing the event listener to `mouseup`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Submit events fire on **form** elements, not button elements.

You're listening for the event in the wrong place.