# Preventing form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with jQuery validation and I've created functions to return true or false if all fields are correctly filled. My problem is how and which function do I use to prevent a form from submitting, if my function returns false.

Thank you all in advance.

--- Edit ---

This is the function (a basic one) that I've made to check if all fields were filled correctly:

```js
$("#btn_create").click(function(){

  $("input").each(function(){
    if($(this).css("border-color") == "rgb(249, 57, 57)"){
      check = false;
      return false;
    } else {
      check = true;
    }
  });

  if(check == false){
    $("#fill").fadeIn("slow");
  } else {
    $("#fill").fadeOut("slow");
  }
});
```

```html
<form method="post" class="create">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="repass" placeholder="Retype Password">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tlm" minlength="9" maxlength="9" placeholder="Contact">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label class="label label-danger" id="fill">Please, fill all fields correctly!</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-lg-12 text-right">
    <button type="submit" id="btn_create" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When the fields are not filled correctly the border-color is red so I ended up doing some validation with that, if there are some input with border-color red,  check = false.

PS.: Before asking this questions I've search for answers such as prevent default... Please do not say its duplicated because I've tried that one and for some reason didn't work.

Comment: Could you please share with code.

Comment: You could just disable the button that submits the form while the form fields are empty. And yes please submit the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Default on Form Submit jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143/prevent-default-on-form-submit-jquery)

Comment: Look here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194673/preventdefault-submitting-form)

Comment: Luckily there are people trying to help in this site instead of saying that is duplicated! @azurinko thanks man that worked

Comment: @BrunoGibellino don't add irrelevant tags next time and also indent your code.

Comment: @RajendranNadar wasn't it about form? wasn't it about validation? wasn't it about javascript? Didn't I use those in my code? So why are they irrelevant? But you are right about one thing I should've indented the code.

Comment: @BrunoGibellino, talking this way, you should've also included bootstrap, input, tag, css, class, id, fadein, fadeout, grid, cycle and etc. tags. But it'd be weird. `javascript`, `jquery` and `html` tags are enough to sort your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#test').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // do your custom stuffs and make a ajax call to submit it manually as per you requirement.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter something" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Try this code it should work.